# Is path animation possible with SVG.js

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

There are many examples of SVG path animation, both natively

http://jsfiddle.net/FVqDq/

and with Raphael.js

http://jsfiddle.net/d7d3Z/1/

```
p.animate({path:"M140 100 L190 60"}, 2000, function() {
    r.animate({path:"M190 60 L 210 90"}, 2000);
});
```

How is this possible with the [svg.js library](http://www.svgjs.com/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not yet possible with [svg.js](https://svgjs.dev/). I have been looking into it and it will be a rather large implementation. As I try to keep the library small it will never be part of the library itself, but I might write a plugin. Although at the moment I do not have much time on my hands so all help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

This is now possible with SVG.js out of the box if you use [paths with equal commands](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/shape-elements/#path-plot) but different values.

But we also have a [path morphing plugin for SVG.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.pathmorphing.js) which is probably the thing you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Wout, I will try figure out how to do this. Do you have any suggestions about where to start? For instance, would it be acceptable to use the SMIL <animation> tags as in the first link of the question?
I plan to be able to animate complex paths imported with svg.import.js.

Answer (score 3):

There is a quick and dirty way to animate a line with svg.js:
http://jsfiddle.net/c4FSF/1/

```
draw
    .line(0, 0, 0, 0)
    .stroke({color: '#000', width: 2})
    .animate(1000, SVG.easing.bounce) // Using svg.easing.js plugin(not required)
    .during(function(t, morph) {
        this.attr({x2:morph(0, 100), y2: morph(0, 100)})
    })
```

Animating complex SVG paths as wout said will require a plugin.
Unfortunately I don't (yet) know enough about SVG, but I'm thinking of writing a plugin which would use the [`SMIL` animation tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL). Which is what is used in the first link of the question.

Comment: The problem with SMIL is that you can't stop an animation halfway. You can, but the shape will then just jump back to it's initial state. There is no way to catch the path data at let's say 60% for example. That makes it pretty useless if you throw user interaction in the mix. So in order to implement this a path parser is required. I would really like to write one but time is not on my hands at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

We can make path animation by finding the bounding box of your path and the do like this.

if your path having some clipping -rectangle means like that below

```
<g id="container_svg_SeriesGroup_0" transform="translate(128.8,435)" clip-path="url(#container_svg_SeriesGroup_0_ClipRect)"><path id="container_svg_John_0" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,5" stroke-width="3" stroke="url(#container_svg_John0Gradient)" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 0 -17.25 L 21.7 -112.12499999999999 M 21.7 -112.12499999999999 L 43.4 -51.75 M 43.4 -51.75 L 86.8 -25.875 M 86.8 -25.875 L 108.5 -155.25 "/><defs><clipPath id="container_svg_SeriesGroup_0_ClipRect"><rect id="container_svg_SeriesGroup_0_ClipRect" x="0" y="-155.25" width="118.5" height="148" fill="white" stroke-width="1" stroke="transparent" style="display: inline-block; width: 118.5px;"/></clipPath></defs></g>

var box = $("#"+ path.id")[0].getBBox();
```

create the rectangle based on the  box and the set this rectangle as your clip-path in path.

then increase the width of the rectangle step  by step in jquery.animate.

```
doAnimation: function () {

//cliprect is your clipped rectangle path.

        $(clipRect).animate(
                                 { width: 1000},
                                 {
                                     duration: 2000,

                                     step: function (now, fx) {
                                         $(clipRect).attr("width", now);
                                     }
                                 });


    },
```

jquery.animate step function is used to increase the width of your clip-rect step  by step.

Comment: Thanks @Siva Rajini I'll look into doing this, but using the `.during` call for the steps, as detailed in my answer.

I'm not sure it will work in my case as I want to animate complex paths and 'squiggles'

Answer (score 1):

You can animate paths using the [svg.path.js](http://otm.github.io/svg.path.js/) plugin.

See the first examples (using the `.drawAnimated` method).

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which we've resorted to, is to use textPath and then use a character.

In our case we're using the • entity, but I'm thinking if you create your own typography in .svg, .woff etc, you can have **flat** shapes of any kind.

So you would use your character as in here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wbx8J/3/

```
   /* create canvas */
    var draw = SVG('canvas').size(400,400).viewbox(0, 0, 1000, 1000)

    /* create text */
    var text = draw.text(function(add) {
      add.tspan('•').dy(27)
    })
    text.font({ size: 80, family: 'Verdana' })

    /* add path to text */
    text.path('M 100 400 C 200 300 300 200 400 300 C 500 400 600 500 700 400 C 800 300 900 300 900 300')

    /* visualise track */
    draw.use(text.track).attr({ fill: 'none'/*, 'stroke-width': 1, stroke: '#f09'*/ })

    /* move text to the end of the path */
    function up() {
        text.textPath.animate(3000).attr('startOffset', '100%').after(down)
    }

    /* move text to the beginning of the path */
    function down() {
        text.textPath.animate(3000).attr('startOffset', '0%').after(up)  
    }

    /* start animation */
    up()
```